# How do I server-redirect to the default error page from an error code set with the header() function?

Tags: php, apache, redirect, error-handling, http-status-code-404

I wanna know if there is a posibility of making the **apache** server auto redirect to its **default** error page from *an error code set within the header() function*.

lets say I have my page.php, this page has this:

```
<?php header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found"); ?>
```

The browser (using web dev tools in chrome), shows that the response has been sent but it doesn't redirect to its default error page, maybe is because the file still exists.

*what i want to do, is redirect specific files to the default error pages by myself but keeping the exact URL showing in the browser, is the same action the server does when you enter a non-existing URL*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, you can just configure Apache to use a specific 404 page in httpd.conf and it will keep the URL the same, but deliver the 404 error page:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

and in /404.php, just put something like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Object not found</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Object not found</h1>
        <p>The object <?php echo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?> could not be found on this server.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hmm yeah but what i want to do is to make the server to read my HTTP errod code and automatically redirect to its **default** error page with that code i would find the page by myself if its a custom page not the default

Comment: The server doesn't read the error code, it is delivered directly to the user's web browser in the HTTP header, and it is up to the browser as to what it does when it encounters a 404 error code in the header. Apache's error pages are generated on-the-fly (unless you specify otherwise in httpd.conf) and as far as I am awear, you cannot trigger them to be dispayed if the URL does indeed exist. You could just create a really tiny 404 page that looks exactly like Apache's, couldn't you?

Comment: Yeah my bad the server doesnt read the error code but when the request is delivered to the server doesnt it tries to find the file if it doesnt exist send the 404 and send the 404 page content to the browser to be displayed? but i just wanted to know if it was posible.

Comment: The server does not necessarily send its 404 page, unfortunately, it just blindly includes this 404 error in the header when delivering the page. What you must do is something like I added into my answer, where you have a custom 404 page which Apache's been told to use in httpd.conf. This is the only way to do something like this unfortunately.

Comment: If you have to include the file to make this then is not necesary to put the HTTP header if the server can't deliver the page by itself so there is no need to use header() to make the response code

Comment: There should be no NEED to include the file, that was just me thinking out loud with all of the solutions I could think of. The best and simplest way to do this is to create /404.php and configure Apache to use this as its 404 error page, end of. This method doesn't require the header() or include() :)

Comment: Okay, I just edited my answer to show onlt the simplest solution :)

Answer (score 0):

To get the HTTP response code you can use the [http_response_code()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php) function. Example:

```
if( http_response_code() == 404 )
{
    // Redirect to your valid custom page
    header("Location: http://www.mypage.com/page_not_found.php" );
}
```

Comment: what about the default apache error page? not one created by me i just want the **default** error page of the apache server

Answer (score 0):

Redirect to a page that does not exist. Then you get the apache created 404 because you have, indeed, landed on a page that does not exist.

This allows you to 'decide' who gets that page and who bounces. Of course, if they have a "nofollow" directive in their web client, it'll fail.

I don't know of a way to both Have a php page there And have apache decide 404 after checking the page in question. It has already relinquished control to PHP. So you likely need to push the request back to apache by deflecting to a non-existent file. You could even get funny and redirect to the same file name ... but end it in .html instead of php, and if that does not exist Poof you have a 404 error for web browsers.